# Find line orthogonal to plane that goes through a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Just to be fully upfront, this is a homework problem that I need help with (Calc III).

Here is the problem:

The equation X(t) = **a** + *t* **d** is the parametric equation of a line through the point P: (2,-3,1). The parameter t represents distance from the point P, directed so that the **i** component of **d** is positive. We know that the line is orthogonal to the plane with equation 1x - 1y - 3z= -10.
Find vectors **a** and **d**.

Here is what I have so far.
**a** was easy to find, as it is literally just the vector representation of point P from the origin. **a** = 2**i**-3**j**+1**k**.

What I think I need to do, in order to find a normal vector **n** of the plane (which I'm not sure how I would do, and I think that's what's really keeping me from progressing). This vector will be perpendicular to the plane, so I can then take the projection of **n** onto **a**, which will give me **w** and then the vector (**a** - **w**) should be **d**. I'm very much unsure, so I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: A simple way to find a vector perpendicular to  a plane is provided here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352134/finding-the-vector-perpendicular-to-the-plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the normal vector, you can move the plane to origin, in other words consider the plane $1x - 1y -3z = 0$. Now, this has normal vector $(1,-1,-3)$. So $d$ must be a multiple of this (since it's "a directional vector", it can be placed to begin at any point, only the direction matters). For $t$ to give the distance, $d$ must have length $1$.

Comment: Wow, I think I've been overthinking this waaaay bad. So are you saying that I just need to take that vector (which I realized just now, I do actually know how to find. I had just forgotten for some reason) and convert it into a unit vector? That literally makes so much sense. I'm going to see what that results and follow up.

Comment: Yup. That was the right answer. I feel kinda stupid now, because I know I should have known that, but at least this was suuuper memorable so hopefully it'll stick. Thank you!