# Need help explaining mathematical expression for the margin (distance between separator line and data point)

Tags: linear-algebra

So the books says the following
[image]

I am a bit unclear on the math for this margin.

E.g I do not understand the math expression for $\gamma$.
As far as I understand $\gamma$ is the distance between separator line and nearest point.
But I do not understand the math behind that... Can someone clarify it for me?
[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separating hyperplane is given by the equation:

$$\Theta^T x = 0$$

This means the vector $\Theta$ is normal to the hyperplane ([see here for a good explanation of this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352134/finding-the-vector-perpendicular-to-the-plane)).

The shortest distance from any point to the hyperplane is the magnitude of the projection of that point onto $\Theta$ (because it is the normal).

The projection is just the inner product between the normalized version of $\Theta$ and your vector $x^{(i)}$, which is what $\frac{\Theta}{||\Theta||} x^{(i)}$ is.

This quantity will be positive for points belonging to the $+1$ class and negative for points belonging to the $-1$ class. To get the magnitude you just multiply by $y^{(i)}$.

Comment: I am not completely sure about it.... I do not see how we have projection on a HYPERPLANE. Seems from what you said we have a projection onto a Theta vector. Also what does it mean "magnitude you just multiply by y(i)"? y is -1 or 1 so you do not get the magnitude from that. Maybe sign of a magnitude...|

Comment: Yes, you have a projection onto the theta vector, which is normal to the hyperplane. I'm not sure where "projection on a hyperplane" fits into your question or my answer. When you multiply the projection by $y^{(i)}$ you get its magnitude. $y^{(i)}$ by itself is not a magnitude.

Comment: The projection is $\frac{\Theta^T x^{(i)}}{||\Theta||}$, which is negative for data points with $y^{(i)} = -1$ and positive for data points with  $y^{(i)} = +1$. To get its magnitude, you simply take the absolute value, which is equivalent to multiplying by $y^{(i)}$