# How do I find the equation of an orthogonal complement?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the equation $x-2y-3z=0$. Find parametric equations for the orthogonal complement of $W$.
 
I got $x=t,\;y=-2t,\;z=-3t$. Can anyone confirm?

Thanks

Comment: This might help for future questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference :)

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct to me; you just pull the coefficients straight out of the plane's equation. The first answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352134/finding-the-vector-perpendicular-to-the-plane) describes why that's true much better than I could.