# What does it mean for a vector to be perpendicular or lie on a Plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-curves

Is one of two question/answer false?

1. [Finding the vector perpendicular to the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352134/finding-the-vector-perpendicular-to-the-plane) (see accepted answer)
2. https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mitmath/1806/blob/master/psets/pset2sol.ipynb (Q1 last part)

In a nutshell: w is vector perpendicular to plane. 1 says any vector on plane is perpendicular to w. 2 says to find a vector on plane in direction of w.

Comment: Are you talking about question 1n in link 2?  If so, note that $v^Tw=1$ does not define a vector perpendicular to a plane (see question and answer 1l: $v^Tw=0$ is required for orthogonality).

Comment: For a plane $w^Tv$ what does w being normal to plane means? See question 1d & 1e (link 2) for reference. @postmortes

Comment: normal means "at right angles to".  If you consider the usual representation of the x-y-z axes, then x and y define a plane, and z is normal to that plane.  The questions from link 2 are intended to help you get familiar with the Cartesian (co-ordinate) representation of these concepts and how you can use simple arithmetic to quickly find geometric properties