# Calculate perpendicular vector that sits on plane

Tags: vectors

I was hoping someone could help me out with some vector math

Say I had 3 3D points, A, B, C, which form a plane called ABC.
I would like to move point B by 10 units, along a vector that is perpendicular to the vector AC, and sits on the plane ABC.

How do I calculate the vector that is perpendicular to AC, and sits on the plane ABC?

[image]

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352134/finding-the-vector-perpendicular-to-the-plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector you need to find is b
Question gives us two conditions that it lies in plane ABC and is perpendicular to AC 
Let's assume that equation of ABC is 
$ax+by+cz=d$

So that vector should satisfy this equations

$(a,b,c) \cdot b = 0$

$b \cdot AC = 0$

Or you can just take cross product of AC and normal vector of plane ABC

$(a,b,c)*AC$